# What is the correct way to 'fix' a site originally installed an developed using Composer, but deployed using FTP?

Tags: composer, deployment

I have put together a site using the Drupal Varbase distribution. To do this I installed using composer, this is my first project using Composer. Now that I'm done in development I'm working on installing to our production server. I created the database and populated with the data from development, uploaded the code-base using FTP to 'public_html' on production and then proceeded to try load up the site. That's when I got my first 500 Server Error:

```
[17-Mar-2020 22:15:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/vuunifcm/public_html/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vuunifcm/public_html/autoload.php on line 16
[17-Mar-2020 22:15:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/vuunifcm/public_html/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vuunifcm/public_html/autoload.php on line 16
[17-Mar-2020 22:15:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/vuunifcm/public_html/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/vuunifcm/public_html/autoload.php on line 16
```

I am used to all the files required by a site being contained in the site's root folder, which for me is typically 'public_html'. It seems that composer is installed a level up and somehow the error is trying to reference components in higher directories where composer would be. I thought composer was more of a utility and not part of the actual website, but realise now I'm mistaken, so I uploaded the Composer files from the parent directory.

However, when I ran the Varbase install using Composer back when I created the site on the dev server, it placed the site in a folder called 'docroot', no 'public_html'. I had thought I would look for references to 'docroot' and see whether changing these instances to 'public_html' would help. I found them in the composer files. However, changing them just led to this:

```
[17-Mar-2020 23:09:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/vuunifcm/vendor/composer/../../docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vuunifcm/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[17-Mar-2020 23:09:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/home/vuunifcm/vendor/composer/../../docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vuunifcm/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[17-Mar-2020 23:09:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/vuunifcm/vendor/composer/../../docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/vuunifcm/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/home/vuunifcm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/home/vuunifcm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/home/vuunifcm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/vuunifcm/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[17-Mar-2020 23:09:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /home/vuunifcm/public_html/index.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/vuunifcm/public_html/index.php on line 16
```

Could this be the source of my problems or was my approach wrong? I feel like I've gone in totally the wrong direction. Can this be 'fixed', or do I need to start over with a different approach? I know there might be a workaround, but I don't want to be messing with workarounds everytime I need to update the site from here.

Just to confirm that the files do exist, this is part of how my folder structure looks:

```
|-- public_html
|   └── core
|       └── lib 
|           └── Drupal \ Core \ DrupalKernel.php
└── vendor
    └── composer
        └── ClassLoader.php
```

Comment: You need to point your domain/vhost to this docroot folder. And maybe have Composer on your server.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should have uploaded to keep my files in /docroot as on my dev server? My cPanel does not let me change the main folder associated with the domain, so I was wondering should I have access to be able to do this, or get my hosting support to change?

Comment: I ran "composer" from a terminal and clarified I do have access to Composer 1.8.6 on the server. Not the same version as mine...1.9.3 though

Comment: You don't need composer server-side if you deploy the files via FTP. You only need to transfer all files you produced locally with composer to the server. It's odd, though, that your web hosting includes command line access but doesn't allow you to edit the vhost settings to point the domain at `web/`.

Comment: You're missing the vendor folder it looks like, which should be one level above your webroot according to the error.

Comment: https://www.morpht.com/blog/drupal-and-composer-part-1-understanding-composer